# iphone uidatepicker in actionsheet with toolbar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios, uidatepicker

I have looked everywhere and I could not find a 'good' solution to display a uidatepicker when a tableviewcell is tapped. In the following screenshot, the datepicker slides up from the bottom and the background of the view is dimmed. There are done and cancel buttons on the toolbar within the view that holds the datepicker.
appreciate your help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting 3.2 or higher, just assign a view containing the picker and whatever buttons you need as the cell's `inputView`, override the cell's `canBecomeFirstResponder` method (if necessary) so it can become the first responder, and call `becomeFirstResponder` on it when tapped.

If you're still targeting earlier versions, you'll have to add that view with the picker and buttons to the hierarchy, animate the sliding, and so on all manually.

Comment: uitableviewcell does not have inputview. I have a uitableviewcell with date/time displayed by its textlabel. What I would like to do is when I tap on the uitableviewcell, slide up the uidatepicker with a done and cancel button.

Comment: @Jay: UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, which is a subclass of UIResponder, which is where `inputView` is defined.

Comment: `inputView` is a read-only property on views that are not "input-able". I had to use a custom cell with a `UITextField`. But now, I have a flashing caret that I don't know how to disable. Any idea?

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys: You can always override the `inputView` property in a subclass, either to make it readwrite or to make it statically return the appropriate value.